# Encryption using bouncy castle without Initialization Vector

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle, jasypt

I am using jasypt with the BouncyCastle provider for my encryption and decryption.

When I looked into the jasypt code, it does not deal with IV parameters. Does JASYPT use a fixed IV or will BouncyCastle generate a random/fixed IV?

If BouncyCastle does that, where can I find the source?

Comment: Did you find the information? I am currently looking for it.